# cancel intent service from broadcast broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I'm sending a local notification with a cancel button and when I click it, I want to cancel my intent service but the event is not getting called.

I can cancel the intent service using an activity, but when is from a notification, it is not working.

My BroadcastReceiver (the Log is showing).

```
class EventsReceiver: BroadcastReceiver(){
    var onEvent = {}
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.i("EventsReceiver", "onReceive")
        when(intent?.action){
            Constants.ACTION_EVENT_CANCEL -> {
                Log.i("EventsReceiver", "cancel")
                onEvent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The onReceive is getting called when I click the notification button but when I call the onEvent(), the cancelTrip() function is not getting called.

My Intent Service:

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        notificationHelper = NotificationHelper(this)
        receiver = EventsReceiver ()
        receiver.onEvent = {
            cancelTrip()
        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION_EVENT_CANCEL))
    }
```

The activity function that cancels the intent service:

```
private fun cancel(){
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_EVENT_CANCEL)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
```

How I create my local notification:

```
val notif = NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
        notif.setContentTitle("My App")
        notif.setContentText("Canceled trip")
        notif.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
        val notifIntent = Intent(ctx, MenuActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx,0,notifIntent,0)
        notif.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        val cancelIntent = Intent(ctx, EventsReceiver::class.java)
        val cancelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx,0,cancelIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
        notif.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, ctx.getString(R.string.cancel_trip), cancelPendingIntent)
        service.notify(NOTIFICATION_CANCEL_ID, notif.build())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val cancelIntent = Intent(ctx, EventsReceiver::class.java)
```

It's because you didn't specify the action (while creating the notification) so in here `when(intent?.action)`
you have different action then `Constants.ACTION_EVENT_CANCEL`.

try using this:

```
val cancelIntent = Intent(Constants.ACTION_EVENT_CANCEL)
```

or

```
val cancelIntent = Intent(ctx, EventsReceiver::class.java)
cancelIntent.action = Constants.ACTION_EVENT_CANCEL
```